# how to use input in a function in python

Tags: python

I just want to use input, in a function in python.
this is my code:

```
    print("I can tell you the maximum of 3 numbers")


def max_num(num1, num2, num3, false=None):
    num1 = input("enter first number")
    num2 = input("enter second number")
    num3 = input("enter third number")

    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    elif num1.isdigit(False) and num2.isdigit(False) and num3.isdigit(False):
        print("no number available")
    else:
        return num3

    return max_num()
```

but when I run this code, Just first line (print), runs succesfully.
what is wrong?
I would be thankful.

Comment: The value returned from *input()* is a string. Therefore your comparisons are lexical rather than numeric. As shown, that code is not runnable. If the first line is unindented then you'll get one line printed then nothing else will happen

Comment: What's the purpose of ```false=None```?

Comment: There are so many things that are wrong in this code. Uncalled function, unused mandatory parameters, incorrect use of `isdigit`, incorrect aggregation of the tests (`and` instead of `or`), potentially infinite recursive behavior on input of 3 non digits... My advice: read a python tutorial and start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a function with parameters, make sure that these parameters don't come inside the definition of the function.
The code also has some indentation and logical mistakes.
This is a corrected version.

```
print("I can tell you the maximum of 3 numbers")

num1 = input("Enter the first number:")
num2 = input("Enter the second number:")
num3 = input("Enter the third number:")

def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if not num1.isdigit() or not num2.isdigit() or not num3.isdigit():
    return "Wrong Input"
    
else:
    num1,num2,num3=int(num1),int(num2),int(num3)
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    
    else:
        return num3

print(max_num(num1,num2,num3))
```

Comment: isdigit() is a method that can only be used on strings. So '4'.isdigit() will return True, while 4.isdigit() causes an error.

Comment: It is the reason why I didn't convert the nums back to integers for comparing. It can be done but is not a necessity as string comparison works just fine.

Comment: Woah! I didn't know that comparing numbers as strings caused problems like these.
Also didn't know about the PEP. 
Thanks for the information. I have corrected the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What does `return max_num()` even mean? You should return a number, and a number is already returned in all possible branches.

If you want to call this function, try something like `print(max_num(1, 2, 3))` at the end of the script.

Also, it is a bit confusing: are you planning to pass in the three numbers by functions arguments or user input? Because you are attempting to do both right now.

Comment: But if the original poster is asking for ```num1```, ```num2```, ```num3``` within ```max_num()```, there's little point in having the parameters.

Comment: A yeah I realised, passing them as parameters just to override them with user input confused me lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that function like print(max_num(num1, num2, num3)), you are still create the function but not calling it.

Comment: btw your code in the last line return max_num() is nonsense , so you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are *lots* of issues with this code, but to answer your original question "Why does `input` never get called?", the answer is simple:

You have defined the function `max_num`, but you have never *called* it. Only once a function is called does the code inside run.

So in your script, you simply need to remove all the input parameters in your function definition (as they are never used), and add the line:

```py
max_num()
```

Then you'll need to fix all the other quirks :)

Happy coding